# How to get all the values in a row of a DB relation and assign each of them to a variable in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to find a way to have access to all the values in a row.

The following code returns one cell. If I change `select id` to `select *`, I have access to the row but how can I break it apart?

```
string find_user = "select id from users where userName = '" + un + "'";

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(find_user, con))
    {
        con.Open();
        user_id = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

        /* use to pass the info to all the pages */
        Session.Add("u_id", user_id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use `SELECT id, secondColumn, thirdColumn, ...`? But first you need to read about [SQL injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access additional columns using `.ExecuteScalar()`, [per the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar?view=netframework-4.8):

> Executes the query, and returns the first column of the first row in the result set returned by the query. Additional columns or rows are ignored.

Although it is not a route that I would recommend, you can iterate through the fields by using an index on a data reader:

```
SqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
// for the query's result set, this while loop will go through all the records
while (dataReader.Read())
{
    // for the current record, this for loop will go through all the fields
    for (int i = 0; i < dataReader.FieldCount; i++)
    {
        var value = dataReader[i]; // do what you need with the data here
    }
}
```

A **better approach** would be to specify the field names in the SQL query instead of using `SELECT *`, then get the values from the data reader by the specific field names (not relying on the order of the fields in the DB).

Also, you have a **SQL injection vulnerability**. You should look up what this means and how to parameterize a query.